# AngularJS: "TypeError: Cannot call method '$broadcast' of null"

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

I'm new to AngularJS and am working on my first mobile application starting with the Ionic Framework. I have a section where I have the user click on a "write review" button. This in turn opens an Ionic modal that has a form attached to it. When the user fills in the form and hits post I will be doing something with that data then the function it calls destroys the modal window. The error gets thrown after the form is submitted and I have the data everytime I open the write review button.

Code that opens the modal:

```
  <a ng-controller="openReviewCtrl" ng-click="openModal()" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
    Write a Review (10 POINTS)
  </a>
```

Review form Template:

```
<div class="modal" >
  <header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Write Review</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
  </header>
  <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
    <form class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="review.author"  name="fullName">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea placeholder="Review" cols="50" ng-model="review.text"  name="review"></textarea>
      </label>
      <button class="button button-full button-positive"  ng-click="writeReview(review)" />Post</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

And finally my Controller code (currently just logs data):

```
.controller('openReviewCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
    $scope.master = {};
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/review.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  }, {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  });

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  //Be sure to cleanup the modal
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
     $scope.writeReview = function(review) {
        console.log(review);
        $scope.modal.remove();
  };
})
```

Upon click of "Write Review" modal opens.
Data gets written in and submitted.
Logs what was written fine and closes Modal.
Upon clicking "Write Review" again throws error
Post button resets page and cancel does not work

```
TypeError: Cannot call method '$broadcast' of null
    at ionic.views.Modal.inherit.show (http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:31554:26)
    at Scope.$scope.openModal (http://angular.dev:8888/www/js/controllers.js:49:18)
    at http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:17182:21
    at http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:33774:11
    at Scope.$eval (http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:18939:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:19039:23)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:33773:15)
    at http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:9578:10
    at forEach (http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:7272:20)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (http://angular.dev:8888/www/lib/js/ionic.bundle.js:9577:5)
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to create a new modal object using the  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl method, instead of reusing the old modal object.  Once the modal object is removed the angular bindings and $scope are destroyed and not available when you reopen it.  The error comes from the modal trying to call broadcast on a $scope object that has been set to null.

I suspect your code should look something like this (I'm not sure when you have to call "modal.show()" so that might have to be moved):

```
.controller('openReviewCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
    $scope.master = {};

  function closeModal() {
    if ($scope.modal) {
      $scope.modal.remove();
      delete $scope.modal;
    }
  }

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/review.html', function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
      modal.show();
      }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      });
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    closeModal();
  };
  //Be sure to cleanup the modal
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    closeModal();
  });

  $scope.writeReview = function(review) {
        console.log(review);
        closeModal();
  };
})
```

Presumably it might also be possible to fix the ionic modal code to be reusable, but I've not looked at this.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me understand a lot clearer what was going on. This worked with one minor edit. The modal objects method is modal.show() instead of modal.open(). Once I got that it works perfectly. Opens a new modal window and can post the data. Upon opening one again the modal form is reset. Thank you!

Comment: oops, sorry, open() was a typo, fixed now.